# How to render a new layout for custom page in Spree Commerce

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, layout, spree

I am working in Spree commerce application. There I made a custom home page.
for this home page I want to render a new layout.

I created a new layout file also for that, under *app/views/layouts/landing.html.erb* but no default css was calling in this case. please have a look on below snapshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr4gP.png)

Controller Code: app/controllers/home_controller

```
 class HomeController < Spree::StoreController
  layout 'landing'
  def index
  end
 end
```

Layout: app/views/layouts/landing.html.slim

```
doctype html
html
head
title
  | Multistore
= csrf_meta_tags
= csp_meta_tag
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
body
= yield
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Anand. Please supply your HTML and CSS so we can help.

Comment: @MikePoole please check above controller and layout code. and please let me know what else you need.

Answer (score 0):

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts

You should make layout file in app/views/layouts directory.

In this case, try to move `landing.html.slim` in `app/views/layouts/landing.html.slim`

Comment: It is in Layout directory. Sorry for not to be mention the right path. I have edited path.

Comment: did you add tab or space (indent) like this gist https://gist.github.com/hmans/6918282 ?